# How do I contain two rigid bodies with a relative position, while ignoring rotation?

Tags: physics, joints

This question is physics engine agnostic (could be Box2D, Bullet, whatever).

I have two rigid bodies, each with a single fixture/shape. One is a sphere, and one is a box.

I'd like the box to rotate independently of the sphere, but I'd like the relative position of both to remain fixed. So for example, if the sphere rolls, the box would move with its position but not rotate. Likewise if the box hits something I'd like the sphere to also respond to the impact.

Is there a simple way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be done with a joint constraint.

In Bullet, if you want rotation in a single plane, it's the [Hinge Constraint](https://pybullet.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtHingeConstraint.html). For rotation in any direction, it's the [Point to Point Constraint](https://pybullet.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtPoint2PointConstraint.html).

In PhysX, the single plane version is a [Revolute Joint](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/guide/Manual/Joints.html#revolute-joint), while the any-rotation version is a [Spherical Joint](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/guide/Manual/Joints.html#spherical-joint).

In Box2D, it's a [Revolute Joint](https://box2d.org/documentation/md__d_1__git_hub_box2d_docs_dynamics.html#autotoc_md86) (since there's only one plane to consider in 2D, there's no distinguishing between a hinge and a ball-and-socket style joint here).

Engines using these libraries might rename these constraints for internal naming consistency. For instance, in Unity, even though it uses PhysX/Box2D under the hood, it renames them to [HingeJoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-HingeJoint.html) and [HingeJoint2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-HingeJoint2D.html) respectively.

Comment: Note that with just a physics constraint like this, the joint won't resist the box rotating relative to the sphere under outside forces like gravity. So if you have the box above the sphere, it'll tend to tip over and get dragged behind the sphere as it rolls. If you want the box to stay upright, like the head of Star Wars droid BB-8 riding on top of its rolling spherical body, then you'll want to either apply forces/torques resist the box's fall, or skip the physics for this and [use following scripts as shown here to get a bobblehead effect](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/197194/39518).